# Why are my Akeeba Backup files suddenly a few MB smaller?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am noticing that many of the Akeeba backup files are three or four MB smaller after the recent Joomla v3.7.4 update.

The Joomla v3.7.4 install file isn't any smaller so I'm wondering if the 3.7.4 update performs a housekeeping function such as deleting old libraries, log files or other code?

Or is there some other recent change I am not aware of (e.g. myjoomla.com audits storing less files on the website)?

I am using the latest version of Akeeba Backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It runs `administrator/components/com_admin/script.php` which does some housekeeping like that.

There are functions to clear logs and delete unused files.

However, I've personally not noticed smaller files in Akeeba after the update.

Answer (score 2):

myjoomla-upgradefile.zip is a transient file and should never be found on a joomla site - unless the upgrade of the myJoomla.com connector failed. This file is downloaded and consumed as needed. It can safely be deleted.

Kindest regards
Phil.
(Owner of the myJoomla.com service)

Comment: Thank-you Mr Taylor, I only looked at one example closely and my assumption that this was the case for all the websites I look after could easily be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Akeeba Extract Wizard to decompress the backup files and compared folder sizes until I found the differences.

The Gantry v4.1.32 to 4.1.33 update reduced installed folder sizes by a few hundred KB but the main culprit was myjoomla.com where the 4.2 MB `/plugins/system/bfnetwork/bfnetwork/tmp/myjoomla-upgradefile.zip` file has been removed.

I am accepting Richard's answer as the best answer because he quite rightly points out that there is some housekeeping done by Joomla installs, identified the file with the code and this is probably more useful to other readers than my particular circumstances.